# Erro mysql na hora de importar tabelas

Tags: mysql

Quando eu faço um import de 44 tabelas o mysql me retorna o seguinte erro:

> #1062 - Duplicate entry '0000000001' for key 'PRIMARY'

alguém sabe o que pode ser? e como resolver?

Comment: O que está tentando importar? Magento?

Comment: @marcosvinicius não, é que eu estou fazendo um banco para testes, então peguei o original exportei e agora estou tentando importar

Comment: O banco de destino está vazio?

Comment: @bfavaretto sim

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha o primary é a coluna onde tem o index, aí os numeros não se podem repetir. Dê uma olhada nos dados que está a importar e verifique que cada tabela está a ir para o sitio certo sem duplicados.

Comment: Isso já aconteceu comigo uma vez, e foi porque não tinha colocado minha chave primária como autoincrement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já existe um registro com a chave primária 1, você esta tentando reinserir dados que já existem...

Comment: sim, mas como resolver ?

Comment: Você pode limpar a tabela antes da importação, se tiver certeza que os dados são os mesmos...